# How to simulate the Ctrl-A-D in shell?

Tags: shell, gnu-screen

I'm using DSH to write some script to run programs on multiple servers.

On each machine, I want to first open a new screen, and then run the program on this screen, after that, I need to detach this screen by ctrl-A-D.

The problem is, how to realize the ctrl-A-D by shell script?

Comment: Can't you just use `exit` command? Anyway, check `xdotool key` to simulate keyboard from command line.

Comment: A lot of screen key-commands have corresponding command-line options. Check the manpage.

Comment: Thanks, xdotool solves the problem!

Comment: Is [this](http://www.netfort.gr.jp/~dancer/software/dsh.html.en) the DSH you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, the dancer's shell or the distributed shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to simulate an interactive `screen` session in this detail. Just create a new session without attaching to it in the first place.

```
screen -d -m 'program arg1 arg2'
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an indirect solution.